# ListView not refreshing

Tags: java, android, listview

I use the ListView just doesn't refresh unless I leave the activity and come back to it

```
for(int k = 0; k < toDelete.size(); k++){
    Log.v("removed", files.get(toDelete.get(k)));
    Integer record = toDelete.get(k);
    files.remove(record);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
list.invalidate();
```

I can see that the correct item is being removed via the log but it still stays on the display until the activity is exited.

Comment: where is this code being executed? I assume it's running on the UI Thread, is it?

Comment: What's the size o the 'files' after the loop? has it really change?

Comment: Yeah the size doesn't appear to be decreasing after the loop. Is there a way to get it to immediately remove the item?

Comment: i asssume 'files' is a Map..for that to use properly, you have to make sure that the objects you're putting in have the equals() and hashCode() properly implemented on the object you're putting in...missing things like this might make the Map misbehave.

Comment: oh no 'files' is an ArrayList of strings, just storing the first part of a file name

Comment: can you try with this one : listview.setAdapter(adapter);  below is working code for me:  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);
      
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         list.invalidate();

Comment: so just use "listview.setAdapter(adapter)" instead of "setListAdapter(adapter)"? it didn't work, thanks though

Comment: @EatBearsForBreakfast as you wrote a solution in your question. Please write it down in answer section..

Answer (score 0):

Solution: it wasn't working because I'd used Integer instead of int. int is a primitive type whereas Integer is an object